# Why does my app crash in the emulator?

Tags: java, android, passwords, android-edittext

I just started programming a little password manager but every time I run it in the emulator, it crashes and I get the following error:

> android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Is everyone seeing the mistake?

MainActivity.java:

```
package de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button login;
EditText masterpassfield;
String masterpass;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    masterpassfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masterpass);
    masterpass = "password";
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(masterpassfield.getText().toString() == masterpass) {

                Intent success = new Intent(view.getContext(), Passwords.class);
                startActivityForResult(success, 0);

            }

        }});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/masterpass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/masterpass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/masterpass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/masterpasstext"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean and running your app.

Comment: And please avoid using offensive words in your questions.

Comment: `Dafuq is the mistake :(?` Great title... Please give your Questions a meaningful title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Project -> Clean`** seems to be the only solution to me.

Trying cleaning your project a few times and then build it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Project -> Clean and also check if there are any warnings in any .xml file. If there are any the R.class will not be generated correctly.